# How to Migrate Extensions from Old Elastix to New Elastix Server

Tags: pbx

We have have Elastix 1.5.2-2.3 and there are more than 50 extensions in PBX. Recently we installed Elastix 2.3.0.

**Now we want to migrate(Export and Import) extensions from Old Elastix to newly installed Elastix.**

I downloaded the extensions from the old server

[image: Old Elastix]

and tried to upload in new server but it gave me this message:

[image: New Elastix Server]

And when I retried to upload the CSV file it was showing me this error message although the file is in .csv format.

[image: error message]

I would really appreciate any input!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by doing the following:

1. Download the CSV format from Newer Elastix by going to the *Batch Extension* tab.
2. Download the CSV file from your old Elastix by going to the *Batch Extension* tab.

If you diff both files you will find that there is an extra header by the name of "Tech" in the Newer Elastix CSV and the value is "Sip" (which you need to repeat in case the older users don't have this value in front of them).

Now copy all the data (everything except the header) from your old Elastix CSV to the New Elastix CSV (do not change the header of New Elastix CSV).

In short, you will be using the header of the New Elastix CSV and the data of the Old Elastix CSV (except its header).

Now save the file and upload it onto your Newer Elastix System.